# Sort JArray alphabetically inside of a dynamic method

Tags: c#, .net

```
"ethernet":[
{
"name":"Ethernet",
"MacAddress":"24-1C-04-11-BF-41",
"Status":"Up",
"LinkSpeed":"100 Mbps",
"MediaType":"802.3",
"AdminStatus":"Up",
"NetworkName":"Unidentified network",
"DriverInfo":"Driver Date 2015-04-05 ",
"Description":"Realtek PCIe GBE Family ",
"LinkLayerAdress":"24-1C-04-11-BF-41",
"GUID":"{B0D12A82-506B-4C8A-B5BD-3F8",
"PortNotAuthenticated":"False",
"InterfacePaused":"False",
"LowPower":"False",
"Disconnected":"False"
},
{
"name":"Ethernet 2",
"MacAddress":"70-88-6B-89-C6-FC",
"Status":"Up",
"LinkSpeed":"100 Mbps",
"MediaType":"802.3",
"AdminStatus":"Up",
"NetworkName":"Unidentified network",
"DriverInfo":"Driver Date 2015-09-17 ",
"Description":"Realtek USB GbE Family ",
"LinkLayerAdress":"70-88-6B-89-C6-FC",
"GUID":"{C2A0D6A5-0769-493A-BD4A-D3E",
"PortNotAuthenticated":"False",
"InterfacePaused":"False",
"LowPower":"False",
"Disconnected":"False"
}
]
```

I have this array of JSON objects and I would like to order it by the MacAddress entry.

I've seen a lot of solutions ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306430/how-to-sort-a-newtonsoft-jarray)) that utilize a lambda expression to sort the JArray by one of the JObject values, but I'm getting the error below when I try to build it

```
JArray Ethernets_sorted = new JArray(Ethernets.OrderByDescending( obj => obj["MacAddress"]));
```

```
Error   CS1977  Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.
```

I'm assuming that this is the case because the method that has this code is declared as dynamic. How do I cast my lambda expression to a known type?
I'm quite new to C# and .NET, sorry for asking trivial questions. This is running in .NET framework 4.6.2 through Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like in the example you linked: You have to ensure the compiler knows what type to expect as result of your lambda function.

```
Ethernets.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.Value<string>("MacAddress"))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue! I tried to give a +1 but I don't have enough reputation yet :(